# How to include prettier automatic fixes into vue serve task

Tags: vue.js, webpack, eslint, vue-cli, prettier

i want to integrate prettier in my vue application, so that it work, weht files instantly changes.

It works, when i use my "yarn run lint --fix", but i don´t want to activate it manuelly. 
I want that it takes action in my "yarn serve" task. Can someone please show me his/her vue.config.js file?

I am using the standard vue-cli.

Thanks a lot!